# On the click of the cell i want to give the functionality like the general radio button

Tags: iphone

I am able to select - unselect the particular row using the custom UIButton in the UITableView. Now i want to make the whole row enable for the selection on click.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath 
{   

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


if (cell == nil) 
{

    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    UIButton  *rdoBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    rdoBtn.frame=CGRectMake(7, 15, 28, 28);
    [rdoBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radiobut1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [rdoBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radiobut2.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    rdoBtn.tag=2;
    [rdoBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(radioBtnPressed:event:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:rdoBtn];
}


UIButton *btn=(UIButton*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];

if([appDelegate.countryName isEqualToString:[dict objectForKey:@"Country_Name"]])
{
    btn.selected = YES;
}
else
{
    btn.selected = NO;
}

}
```

This is the code for the selection of the radio button as per selection.

```
-(void)radioBtnPressed : (id)sender event : (id)event
{

NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:MyCntryTbl];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [MyCntryTbl indexPathForRowAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];

if (indexPath != nil)
{
    appDelegate.countryName = [[appDelegate.MyCntryArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Country_Name"];
    appDelegate.countryCode = [[appDelegate.MyCntryArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Country_Code"];

    [MyCntryTbl reloadData];
}
}
```

Simply all the things are working proper when i click on particular radio button, but now i want to do same process on the click of any place of the whole cell of the table. So please help me for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add UITableViewDelegate method :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    [self radioBtnPressed:event:];  
}
```

and do not forget *tableView*.delegate = self;

Comment: of course, I've used abstract [self radioBtnPressed:event:]. You should call proper your IBAction "radioButtonClick".

Comment: Why i have used this, because of the Touch event to fire with specified values to get on click.